# How to import conversions from custom object into adwords from salesforce sales cloud?

Tags: lead-conversion, google, adwords

I've implemented standard salesforce & google AdWords integration. Though, this integration only syncs Lead & Opportunity object. How do I connect a custom salesforce object with Adwords and define conversion actions for the same?

Context - There is a standard integration available between Salesforce sales cloud and google adwords. When I connect google adwords with salesforce, it can fetch data from sales cloud into google adwords basis on the "GCLID" (Google click identifier) value captured at the time of lead generation. 
Currently, I can only see option to sync Lead and Opportunity object from sales cloud into google adwords.
Now we've created a custom object called "Enquiry". How do I sync this custom object in google adwords?

Comment: Can you give us some more background?  Which Adwords integration are you using?  What are the conversion actions that you're referring to?

Comment: Adwords provide standard integration with salesforce. Using which I can import lead & opportunity data in adwords account and basis on the various lead status or opportunity status, can define conversion actions. This conversion actions can be further used in adwords campaign as a conversion and with the help of same data, adwords campaigns can be optimized.
Currently, adwords only provide option to sync lead & opportunity data. I've a custom object created in salesforce, how do I sync that same?

Comment: Thanks for the extra info!  Not sure if that integration provides custom object sync capabilities.  If you can include a link to the integration (or docs that tell you what it is and how to set it up), that would also be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Google adwords (Google ads) doesn't provide an option to sync custom objects. Currently, it supports only Lead & Opportunity object.

Here is the link to [official documentation](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6179720?hl=en) provided by Google for integration purpose.